# escaping colon with node js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, escaping, nodemailer

I am using [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) to send an email to a client with NodeJS and expressJS,
my transporter variable looks like this

var passHash = hash(password);

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: "company",
    to: mail, //receiver
    subject: 'subject', // Subject line
    html: '<a href="my.url.com:8080/reset/' + passHash + '">Click Here </a>'

};
```

edit: i also want to add that when i console.log the line in "html:" will output exactly what i want it to output, which is exactly whats written there

```
<a href="my.url.com:8080/reset/abcbdc2312380089128"> Click Here </a>
```

but looks like node or js in general dont like the ":" colon charachter in **my.url:PORT_NUMBER**  and doesnt display the link in the mail as a link at all,the service is still in development but there are some things in need to do and i need this one to work, i have tried escaping with '\\' and '\' but nothing seems to work, i will appreciete any directions, if more information is needed please let me know.
thanks.

Comment: Is this `my.url` a variable? And this `PORT_NUMBER`? You're using them as strings...

Comment: When you say `'\' and '\'` do you mean `my.url\\:PORT_NUMBER` ?

Comment: my.URL would be just a URL like Google.com, its not a variable its a string, and PORT_NUMBER would just be a number like 8080 so its also a string and yes Micah, that's what I meant, didn't realize double backslash here works the same

Comment: Maybe you can make up a more realistically looking example with numeric port number and `some_variable` defined.

Comment: i did, but i dont see how thats relevent since the problem is with the ":" colon character